# playa not returning parents

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, parent

My site has events. members can apply for an event. I want to prevent them applying more than one time for an event to prevent duplicates.

My set up is as follows:

- channel event
- 2 channels for accreditation (internal and external) with the same field group attached, one of these fields is a playa field with the events. My registered visitors apply to these events with a safecracker form.

So in my template i want to see if the current user has allready made an entry in the accreditation channels by using the playa:parent_ids tag. However, this is not returning anything.

```
{exp:playa:parent_ids channel="external_accreditation|accreditation" show_expired="true" show_future_entries="true" status="Open|Pending|Accepted" field="acc_rel_event"}
```

I have playa links installed on my system, and that addon does return the proper parents: [image]

Or am i trying to do this in an overly complex way?

Here's my complete test template, where the child stuff is outputting, only the parent stuff is not:

```
{if logged_out}{redirect=''}{/if}
{embed='_partials/.template'}
{exp:channel:entries
    channel='event'
    limit='1'
    dynamic='no'
    url_title='mvv-sparta-rotterdam'
}
    {exp:stash:set}
        {stash:pagetitle}{title}{/stash:pagetitle}
        {stash:pagecontent}
            <div>
            entry_id: {entry_id} - channel short name: {channel_short_name} url_title: {url_title}<br>
            total parents: 
            {exp:playa:total_parents channel="external_accreditation|accreditation" show_expired="true" show_future_entries="true" status="Open|Pending|Accepted"}<br>
            parent_ids: 
            {exp:playa:parent_ids channel="external_accreditation|accreditation" show_expired="true" show_future_entries="true" status="Open|Pending|Accepted"}<br>
            child_ids: 
            {exp:playa:child_ids channel="external_accreditation|accreditation" status="Open|Pending|Accepted"}<br>
            playa:parents: 
            {exp:playa:parents channel="external_accreditation|accreditation" status="Open|Pending|Accepted" var_prefix="acc"}
            {acc:entry_id}
            {/exp:playa:parents}<br>

            </div>
        {/stash:pagecontent}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Is the `exp:playa:parents` inside or outside of a `exp:channel:entries` loop? If it's outside, I believe you need to supply an `entry_id`.

Comment: it's inside. and the debug shows it takes the correct entry id

Comment: Are your statuses’ short names actually Open, Pending, and Accepted (with the capital letters)? Pretty sure that it’s case-sensitive.

Comment: yes they are correct...

Comment: any ideas what could be the case?